# Problem with equivalence relations.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Proof that if $\mathrm{R}_1$ and $\mathrm{R}_2$ are equivalence relations then new relation $\mathrm{R}$ which is determined as $(a\,\mathrm{R}\,b)\ (a\,\mathrm{R}_1\,b\wedge a\,\mathrm{R}_2\,b)$ is also equivalence relation.

Comment: You need to check the three properties of equivalence relations

Comment: You can prove that (i) $R$ is reflexive, (ii) $R$ is symmetric, and (iii) $R$ is transitive. You could also consult https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I've understood that i should provt these 3 properties but how can I show it?

Comment: Recall the definitions of each; also recall that each of $R_1$ and $R_2$ also fulfil that definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Refexive**. Since $(x\,\mathrm{R}_1\,x)$ and $(x\,\mathrm{R}_2\,x)$, $\dots$

2) **Symmetric**. If $(x\,\mathrm{R}\,y)$, then $(x\,\mathrm{R}_1\,y)$ and $(x\,\mathrm{R}_2\,y)$.  Thus $\dots$

3) **Transitive**. If $(x\,\mathrm{R}\,y)$ and $(y\,\mathrm{R}\,z)$, then $\dots$